# What was the nature of sorcery in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars

I am listening to the audiobook *Darth Plagueis*. In the book it mentions that there existed sorcery (at least in the past), and this sorcery had cross-over with the Sith but apparently was not the darkside itself.

This leaves me with some questions. The Force, from what I can tell, while an esoteric, celestial power with the Jedi and Sith pseudo-religous traditions surrounding it, was explicable by science. OTOH, I don't understand how sorcery could be -- was this part of the story a shift from Science Fiction to pure fantasy and magic?

Was the sorcery intertwined with the Force or truly separate? Was it stronger? Would only a Sith practice sorcery, or also Jedi? Could some examples of it be given?

I'm not making any distinction here between Disney and pre-Disney (I'm not even sure if this is a Disney era book), so feel free to draw from either.

This is ***VERY different*** than the question "does magic exist in Star Wars canon" wherein the answer is "no magic exists in the Disney version" because

1. **I'm referencing a book that says it does exist** and
2. *I don't care* about Disney vs. non-Disney

Also

3. I'm specifically asking about ***sorcery*** -- especially that which the Sith (and possibly Jedi) practiced; ***whether that is the same as "magic" or not is part of my question.***

Comment: "The Force was explainable by science." - Citation needed.

Comment: @Adamant Midi-chlorians and such. Of course it isn't explicable by *real* science, but at least science fiction.

Comment: @RogueJedi That doesn't answer my question because it's saying there's no non-force magic in the Disney version and I'm referencing a book that says it does exist and I don't care about Disney vs. non-Disney. Also I'm specifically asking about *sorcery*; whether that is the same as "magic" or not is part of my question.

Comment: If that is the James Luceno book, I've read through it and the only reference to magic in it that I could find referred to the Nightsisters of Dathomir - is that what you are asking about - if so, they did practice magic, but it was just an expression of the Dark Side of the Force.

Comment: The only other reference I can find in it is about sorcery predating the arrival of the Exiles (Dark Jedi from the Second Great Schism/Hundred-year Darkness) on Korriban, which is true, the native Sith species practiced Dark side-based magic before the Exiles arrived. When the Exiles arrived they learned Sith magic but as they were far more powerful in the Dark Side of the Force they developed it even further.